# How to read Wiegand on Raspberry Pi 3 with Node?

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, access-control, wiegand

I've tried numerous tutorials, and I can't get it to work.

Current situation:
- 12V [Access control device](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32888710502.html?storeId=3983022) that is [connected like this](https://github.com/leosac/leosac/wiki/Raspberry-Pi-and-Wiegand:-step-by-step) i.e. Wiegand D0 to GPIO14 (pin 8/Tx) and D1 to GPIO15 (pin 10/Rx), with voltage dividers, shifting 5V to 3.3V.
- Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian Lite OS.
- [Configured the GPIO serial port](https://spellfoundry.com/2016/05/29/configuring-gpio-serial-port-raspbian-jessie-including-pi-3/) i.e. enabling uart and disabling the console.

I am using the [onoff NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/onoff) to read the signals, **but I am not getting anything**.

```
const Gpio = require('onoff').Gpio;
const d0 = new Gpio(8, 'in');
const d1 = new Gpio(10, 'in');

d0.watch((err, value) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  d0.readSync(value);
});

d1.watch((err, value) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  d1.readSync(value);
});

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  d0.unexport();
  d1.unexport();
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The NPM package you're trying to use can only detect changing logic levels on GPIO pins.

You should use [Wiegand NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wiegand) instead.

And I think you have set the wrong pins on your code. Pins 8 and 10 are in fact GPIO14 and GPIO15. The library I linked uses GPIO17 and GPIO18 by default, which are located on pins 11 and 12 of the [connector](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/raspberry-pi-gpio-pinout,6122.html).

Having said that, there is no need to [disable the UART](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/44064/105023) to use pins 8 and 10 as digital GPIO.